# Keyboard resulting wrong keys before OS starts

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, bios, keymap

My keyboard has recently started resulting wrong keys when I try to press any keys on keyboard before booting. The problem came literally out of nowhere. I have no idea why It stopped working and I was able to access the BIOS just fine a week ago with the same keyboard. But now I can't access it, since the <kbd>del</kbd> key just results a random character.

It doesn't work in the boot manager either.

But after booting up Windows 7, the keyboard is working fine.

I've managed to find out some of the wrong keys it sends by smashing some random keys *(miraculously got into a command line by smashing random keys when trying to install linux)*:

- <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>9</kbd> --> <kbd>m</kbd>
- <kbd>numlock</kbd> --> <kbd>e</kbd>
- <kbd>7</kbd> --> <kbd>a</kbd>
- <kbd>7</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> --> <kbd>i</kbd>

**What I've already tried:**

- Reinstalling windows and formating the drive
- Reinstalling keyboard from the device manager
- Resetting BIOS
- Updating drivers
- Checking if USB Legacy mode was enabled from BIOS (using MSI Click Bios), it was enabled.

None of those brought any results.

**My hardware:**

- Motherboard: MSI Z77A-G45
- Processor: Intel i5-3570k
- SSD: Kingston SSDNow v300 120gb
- Keyboard: CM Storm QuickFire TK

Comment: Before troubleshooting everything besides the keyboard, you should of checked to make sure that it wasn't the keyboard it self that was going bad. Please check by placing a different, working keyboard.

Comment: this is a great story, but what's your actual question?  If it's about getting the keyboard to work right, first you have to determine if it's the keyboard itself that failing:  Try a known-good keyboard, try that keyboard on another computer.

Comment: I will be trying that tomorrow when I get hands on another one. But I can say that the keyboard does work with other computers fine. Though there still might be something wrong in my computer specific to this keyboard and I will find out tomorrow if that is true. (Even if there is, it still doesn't fix the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a wild guess, but maybe it's KRO mode?
From the manual:

> Switching between full N key and 6 key rollover
>   In FN-Lock mode pressing the ESC and N key at the same time switches the Keyboard to NKRO mode. Pressing the ESC and 6 key switches the Keyboard to 6KRO mode.

and then a bit later:

> Note: NKRO mode is not supported on MACs and prevents some PCs from booting

Comment: This worked! Though I had to use different key combination for this keyboard. I hold 6 and ESC for few seconds and after that keyboard restarted and was working again. Thank you very much. I must have somehow accidently activated the NKRO mode.